# How to use a character variable to refer to a data.frame in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dynamic number of data.frames depending on input - n_tables.

```
n_tables = 5 ## This may vary between 3 to 12
for(i in 1:n_tables){
    assign(paste0("r", i),data.frame(X = c("a","b","c"),Y = runif(3,0,10)))
}
```

Now, I need to put all these data.frames in a list and subset them. I have tried the below code but not working -

```
t <- paste0("r",1:n_tables)
p <-lapply(t,function(x){(x[x$X == "a",])})
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try `p <- mget(ls(pattern = '^r\\d+'), envir = .GlobalEnv)` or `p <- mget(t, envir = .GlobalEnv)`. Then subset the usual way, for instance with `lapply(p, etc)`.

Comment: Do not use `assign`. Do `mylist <- list()` before the loop and then `mylist[[i]] <- data.frame(...)` in the loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `get()` to fetch the object, i.e.,

```
p <-lapply(t,function(x){x <- get(x);x[x$X == "a",]})
```

such that

```
> p
[[1]]
  X        Y
1 a 5.550481

[[2]]
  X        Y
1 a 5.365116

[[3]]
  X        Y
1 a 5.783017

[[4]]
  X        Y
1 a 2.782952

[[5]]
  X        Y
1 a 2.123357
```

Comment: or perhaps `sapply(mget(t), subset, X == "a", simplify = FALSE)`

Answer (score 1):

We get the objects into a `list` with `mget`, loop over the `list` with `map` and `filter` the rows from the column 'X'

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
map(mget(t), ~ .x %>% 
                   filter(X == "a"))
```